# How to grep Git commits for a certain word?

Tags: git, search, grep, git-log

In a Git code repository I want to list all commits that contain a certain word. I tried this

```
git log -p | grep --context=4 "word"
```

but it does not necessarily give me back the filename (unless it's less that five lines away from the word I searched for. I also tried

```
git grep "word"
```

but it gives me only present files and not the history.

How do I search the entire history, so I can follow changes on a particular word? I intend to search my codebase for occurrences of word to track down changes (search in files history).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grep (search) committed code in the git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-committed-code-in-the-git-history)

Answer (score 1232, accepted):

If you want to find all commits where the *commit message* contains a given word, use

```
$ git log --grep=word
```

If you want to find all commits where "word" was added or removed in the *file contents* (to be more exact: where the number of occurrences of "word" changed), i.e., search the *commit contents*, use a so-called 'pickaxe' search with

```
$ git log -Sword
```

In modern Git there is also

```
$ git log -Gword
```

to look for *differences* whose added or removed line matches "word" (also *commit contents*).

A few things to note:

- `-G` by default accepts a regex, while `-S` accepts a string, but it can be modified to accept regexes using the `--pickaxe-regex`.
- `-S` finds commits where the number of occurrences of "word" changed, while `-G` finds commits where "word" appears in the diff.
- This means that `-S<regex> --pickaxe-regex` and `-G<regex>` do not do exactly the same thing.

The [`git diff` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) has [a nice explanation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9299f84921e0bd076cf998aa852fadb73627756f/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L565-L577) of the difference:

> To illustrate the difference between `-S<regex> --pickaxe-regex` and `-G<regex>`, consider a commit with the following diff in the same file:
>
> ```
> +    return frotz(nitfol, two->ptr, 1, 0);
> ...
> -    hit = frotz(nitfol, mf2.ptr, 1, 0);
> ```
>
> While `git log -G"frotz\(nitfol"` will show this commit, `git log -S"frotz\(nitfol" --pickaxe-regex` will not (because the number of occurrences of that string did not change).

This will show the commits containing the search terms, but if you want to see the actual changes in those commits instead you can use `--patch`:

```
$ git log -G"searchTerm" --patch
```

This can then be piped to `grep` to isolate the output just to display commit diff lines with that search term.  A common use-case is to display diff lines with that search term in commits since and including a given commit - `3b5ab0f2a1` in this example - like so:

```
$ git log 3b5ab0f2a1^.. -G"searchTerm" --patch | grep searchTerm
```

Comment: *-S<string>* and *-G<string>* in `man git log` is so unclear. I had to read and experiment three times to catch the difference.

Comment: @TankorSmash `-S<string>` Look for differences that introduce or remove an instance of <string>.
`-G<string>` Look for differences whose added or removed line matches the given <regex>.

Comment: @m-ric Oh I see, a single string instance, versus an entire line! Thanks

Comment: @m-ric, @TankorSmash: The difference is that `-S<string>` is faster because it only checks if number of occurrences of `<string>` changed, while `-G<string>` searches added and removed line in every commit diff.

Comment: @JakubNarębski I don't understand Steve's edit. I kind of like the `git log --grep=word` you mentioned for the commit message, as opposed to commit content.

Comment: @VonC: Thanks for mentioning it. Reverted, as Steven Penny edit *removed* useful information.

Comment: If you need to search words with space in between,`git log --grep="my words"`.

Comment: @MEM, `--grep` is different from `-S` and `-G`. You can quote the string to each of these arguments.

Comment: Note that if you want to find the word in *any* commit, you need to also run these with "git log -g", because if you've accidentally orphaned a commit, none of the forms here will find it.

Comment: Can you then make `-G` accept fixed string so that you don't have to quote special characters?

Comment: @jamo, if its a special character, it probably has to be quoted. Its very similar to how you use pass regular expressions to `find` or `grep`.

Comment: you might also want to add `--patch` so that you can actually see the code changes: `git log -Sword --patch`

Comment: @JakubNarębski I took the liberty to update the examples, but feel free to revert the edit if you disagree.

Comment: `git log --grep=<term>` can also be case-insensitive by adding `-i` or `--regexp-ignore-case`

Comment: I can't work out how to search for a term with spaces. None of these work git log -S"two words", git log -S "two words", git log -S "two\ words", git log -Stwo\ words

Comment: Interesting that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124914/how-to-search-a-git-repository-by-commit-message/7124949#7124949) to a similar question also talks about using `git grep`, indicating that there seem to be 2 different commands allowing you to do this.  I guess using `git log --grep...` is the preferred way.

Comment: This answer concentrates only on `git log` scope. What if one needs to query the whole repository / all branches?

Comment: @bloody - `git log` can search all branches with `--branches`...

Comment: Actually what I rather meant was `git log --remotes` but you directed me fruitfully. Thanks!

Comment: `Git log -G` is terrific, but it seems to only return the five most recent commits. What if I want more?

Comment: @WilliamJockusch Are you sure that you have more than 5 commits (starting from HEAD by default) where `<pattern>` matches within changes? Because I have just checked that it can return more than 5 commits. Note that by default `git log` uses pager, and shows first page of results then stops for user input.

Comment: Turns out I just needed the spacebar.

Answer (score 268):

`git log`'s pickaxe will find commits with changes including "word" with `git log -Sword`

Comment: This is not entirely precise. -S<string> Look for differences that introduce or remove an instance of <string>. **Note that this is different than the string simply appearing in diff output;**

Comment: While this is generally the right answer, I downvoted only to encourage others to read this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1340245/586983) which has 3 different ways and explains their subtleties.

Comment: gosh! I don't think that's a good reason to downvote a right answer... you weren't confident including the link in a comment would be sufficient encouragement?

Comment: @jakeonrails, That answer should have been an edit to this (older) one, so we don't have these annoying duplicates. But people only want the reputation, instead of a clean answers page.

Comment: Examples of blaming the people instead of the system. Stack Overflow should have more varied and nuanced ways to: divert attention, reward improvement, qualify and quantify, exalt the essence, clarify and drill down. And to digress without detracting, wink wink wince.

Answer (score 49):

After a lot of experimentation, I can recommend the following, which shows commits that introduce or remove lines containing a given regexp, and displays the text changes in each, with colours showing words added and removed.

```
git log --pickaxe-regex -p --color-words -S "<regexp to search for>"
```

Takes a while to run though... ;-)

Comment: This is one of the best so far thanks. Hint: to just list all results without paging, either prepend the command with `GIT_PAGER=cat` or append it with `| cat`

Comment: Specify a path or file would be much faster `git log --pickaxe-regex -p --color-words -S "<regexp to search for>"  <file or fiepath>`

Comment: Can this be modified to display only the lines matching the pattern, instead of the entire diff? (I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51603771/1231241)

Comment: You can add a limit to the output to prevent it from spinning out of control: `git log -n 1000 --pickaxe-regex -p --color-words -S "<regexp to search for>"`

Answer (score 12):

One more way/syntax to do it is: `git log -S "word"`
Like this you can search for example `git log -S "with whitespaces and stuff @/#ü !"`

Answer (score 12):

You can try the following command:

```
git log --patch --color=always | less +/searching_string
```

or using `grep` in the following way:

```
git rev-list --all | GIT_PAGER=cat xargs git grep 'search_string'
```

Run this command in the parent directory where you would like to search.

Comment: I like this method because the commits I'm looking at have hundreds of lines of unrelated changes, and I am only interested in the actual patches that involve the word I'm searching for. To get color use `git log --patch --color=always | less +/searching_string`.

Comment: To find something in the garbage commits use:

`git fsck | grep -Po '(?<=commit ).*' | GIT_PAGER xargs git grep 'search_string'`

Answer (score 4):

To use a Boolean connector on a regular expression:

```
git log --grep '[0-9]*\|[a-z]*'
```

This regular expression searches for the regular expression [0-9]* or [a-z]* in commit messages.

Answer (score 4):

This is useful in combination with [BFG](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) (Git filter branch - not to be confused with *[git-filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)*) and [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/). It just gets the file paths so that you can feed them into one of the two tools I just mentioned.

#### A. Relative, unique, sorted, paths:

```
# Get all unique filepaths of files matching 'password'
# Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69714869/10830091
git rev-list --all | (
    while read revision; do
        git grep -F --files-with-matches 'password' $revision | cat | sed "s/[^:]*://"
    done
) | sort | uniq
```

#### B. Unique, sorted, filenames (not paths):

```
# Get all unique filenames matching 'password'
# Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69714869/10830091
git rev-list --all | (
    while read revision; do
        git grep -F --files-with-matches 'password' $revision | cat | sed "s/[^:]*://"
    done
) | xargs basename | sort | uniq
```

This second command is useful for BFG, because it only accept file names and not repo-relative/system-absolute paths.

There you go. Enjoy using these Bash snippets for as much agony as they caused to me. I hate Bash, so why do I keep using it?

## Dissection

### Get file names/paths only

Any of the following options mean the same ([git-rep documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt--l)):

- `-l`
- `--files-with-matches`
- `--name-only`

> Instead of showing every matched line, show only the names of files that contain
> Blockquote

### Is your pattern: A. Regex v.s. B. Fixed String?

As for `-F`, well, it just means use a fixed string instead a regex for pattern interpretation. [A source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt--F).

Another useful note that belongs here: You can throw in `-i` or `--ignore-case` to be [case insensitive](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt--i).

### Get rid of that stupid leading commit hash

```
sed "s/[^:]*://"
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12297991/10830091).

### Get them unique paths!

```
| sort | uniq
```

Who wants duplicate paths? Not you, not me! Oh hey look, they are sorted too! Enjoy.

Source: me. I have used this for as long as I can remember.
(`man sort` and `man uniq`)

### What about file names without paths?

```
xargs basename
```

You would think `| basename` would work, but no. It does not accept input [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)), but as command line arguments. Here's [an explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108797/394471) for that. Go figure! `basename` basically returns the stem filename without its leading path. `man basename`.

### For method A., I want absolute paths not relative.

Sure, just slap a `realpath` at the end. Like so:

```
) | sort | uniq | xargs realpath
```

Of course you have to use [`xargs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) because `realpath` does not use standard input for input. It uses command-line arguments. Just like `dirname`.

## Inspirations

- Check out this awesome [alternative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27496491/10830091).
- *[Search all of Git history for a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468361/search-all-of-git-history-for-a-string/4468394#4468394)*
- *[File names only using Git grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970788/file-names-only-using-git-grep/48970924#48970924)*

Comment: Thanks for the edits @Peter Mortensen! My answer is looking even crispier now, with these typos and naked URLs fixed. Your edit descriptions are on-point too as they help me avoid repeating those corrected issues.

Answer (score 1):

[vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) is versatile for that kind of examining in Vim.

Use `:Ggrep` to do that. For more information you can install vim-fugitive and look up the turorial by `:help Grep`. And this episode: [exploring-the-history-of-a-git-repository](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-exploring-the-history-of-a-git-repository/) will guide you to do all that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want search for sensitive data in order to remove it from your Git history (which is the reason why I landed here), there are tools for that. GitHub as [a dedicated help page for that issue](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/).

Here is the gist of the article:

> The [BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) is a faster, simpler alternative to git filter-branch for removing unwanted data. For example, to remove your file with sensitive data and leave your latest commit untouched), run:

```
bfg --delete-files YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA
```

> To replace all text listed in passwords.txt wherever it can be found in your repository's history, run:

```
bfg --replace-text passwords.txt
```

> See the [BFG Repo-Cleaner's documentation](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) for full usage and download instructions.

Comment: You might wanna add this answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history instead of here