# Search all of Git history for a string

Tags: git

I have a code base which I want to push to GitHub as open source. In this Git-controlled source tree, I have certain configuration files which contain passwords. I made sure not to track this file and I also added it to the `.gitignore` file. However, I want to be absolutely positive that no sensitive information is going to be pushed, perhaps if something slipped in-between commits or something. I doubt I was careless enough to do this, but I want to be *positive*.

Is there a way to "grep" all of Git? I know that sounds weird, but by "all" I mean every version of every file that ever existed. I guess if there is a command that dumps the diff file for every commit, that might work?

Comment: it's limited in that it'll only search a single branch (master?), but it's pretty close to what you want 
https://github.com/divinity76/SearchGithubHistory.js/blob/master/SearchGithubHistory.js /

Comment: Notwithstanding the 'Correct Answers', your requirement is to check that certain information is not committed publicly - the 'git' answer is only relevant since you are committing the whole history.  Of course if you only commit the current revision, without history (use eg. "git archive"), then a simple 'grep' will suffice.

Comment: not a duplicate. the other question is about just the logs, this one is about *all* of a git history. those are different.

Answer (score 1783, accepted):

Git can search diffs with the -S option (it's called pickaxe [in the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Sltstringgt))

```
git log -S password
```

This will find any commit that added or removed the string `password`. Here a few options:

- `-p`: will show the diffs. If you provide a file (`-p file`), it will generate a patch for you.
- `-G`: looks for differences whose added or removed line matches the given regexp, as opposed to `-S`, which "looks for differences that introduce or remove an instance of string".
- `--all`: searches over all branches and tags; alternatively, use `--branches[=<pattern>]` or `--tags[=<pattern>]`

Comment: If something does wind up committed, is there an easy way to remove it?  Let's assume in this scenario there's a config file that I want to keep, but one line contains a password, which I want to remove from all of my git history.  Any simple way to do that without rewriting every commit?

Comment: @MattD Yes, `git rebase -i <commit>` will do the trick. Relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963261/can-i-rebase-old-commits

Comment: hi, `git log -Gpassword --all`, how to add condition to only search for some file(giving a regex to filter filename+filepath)

Comment: @MattD "without rewriting every commit" - No. You'll have to re-write every commit after the one introducing the password. This tool is the easiest way to clean the repo: http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Comment: In this particular case I'd also throw in a `-i` to make the search case insensitive.

Comment: Note the lack of space between the ```-S``` and ```password```. I had seen other advice that included a space and including one would result in a ```fatal: ambiguous argument```.

Comment: Just an FYI, the above command didn't really work for me.  I did the following: `git log -p -S <YOUR_SEARCH_TERM>`  I stole this info from [this informative article about git pickaxe.](http://www.philandstuff.com/2014/02/09/git-pickaxe.html)

Comment: Rolled back the edit by Geoffrey Hale  The `-S` option does search diffs. Adding space after `-S` changes the meaning of the argument from search term to "revision or path".

Comment: I don't know if this is new, but the linked docs says that `-S` looks for "differences that change **the number of occurrences** of the specified string" (emphasis added.) So if a commit adds the term you're seeking but also removes it from elsewhere, `-S` will not find it. `-G`, OTOH, doesn't do this.

Comment: Thanks! Because this is such a useful reference, I'd add that `-- path/filename` will restrict the search to a file.

Comment: you might also want to add `--patch` so that you can actually see the code changes: `git log -Sword --patch`

Comment: This will not find passwords that were commited as part of the username or email address.

Comment: I love you forever

Answer (score 136):

```
git rev-list --all | (
    while read revision; do
        git grep -F 'password' $revision
    done
)
```

Comment: +1: I would have done "for revision in \`git rev-list --all\`; do git grep… done", but your approach is more reactive, as it greps while the revisions are being found.

Comment: Is it possible to use this on a remote repository (like github)?

Comment: @reesd: Only if you clone it, of course.

Comment: In order to avoid seeing matches from `vendor/cache/` and `public/assets/`, change the `grep` line in this answer to: `git grep -F 'password' $revision | grep -v ':vendor/cache/' | grep -v ':public/assets/'`

Comment: You can get file names only (without commit hash) Also sorted and without duplicates. Check my answer for this. Thanks to this answer's OP from whom I took inspiration.  [Here is my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69714869/10830091)

Comment: This will not find passwords that were commited as part of the username or email address.

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained your solution.

Answer (score 73):

Try the following commands to search the string inside all previous tracked files:

```
git log --patch  | less +/searching_string
```

or

```
git rev-list --all | GIT_PAGER=cat xargs git grep 'search_string'
```

which needs to be run from the parent directory where you'd like to do the searching.

Comment: The second command is significantly slower