# Git search for string in a single file's history

Tags: git

So if I have a file called **foo.rb** and it is giving me an error for a missing method called **bar**, so I want to search the history of **foo.rb** for the string `bar` to see if it was ever defined in the past.

I found this [Search all of Git history for a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468361/search-all-of-git-history-for-string)

But this searches all files. I just want to search in one file.

Comment: Just as an FYI, you can append `-- filename` to a bunch of git commands if you want to limit it to one file.

Answer (score 346, accepted):

For this purpose you can use the -S option to git log:

```
git log -S'bar' -- foo.rb
```

Comment: Or `git log -G'bar' -- foo.rb` to search for diff that contains 'bar' rather than for commits that changed number of occurences of 'bar' (see git-log manpage).

Comment: It didn't work for me with the quotes, I had to use `-Sbar` for it to search for _bar_. Maybe it has something to do with me using the Windows command line.

Comment: in other words, `-G` is for a regex search... this is a great reference, too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4472267/2586761

Comment: to the future me coming here on windows 11 using absolute path to the file did not work. just go to where the file is and use the command above

Comment: In Windows 11 use `"` instead of `'`.

Answer (score 27):

Or maybe you can try this one (from related questions *[Search all of git history for string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468361/search-all-of-git-history-for-string)*)

```
git rev-list --all foo.rb | (
    while read revision; do
        git grep -F 'bar' $revision foo.rb
    done
)
```

It will actually look for file content and not commit messages/patches for any occurence of bar.

Comment: For windows:  `for /F %i in ('git rev-list --all foo.rb') git grep -F bar %i foo.rb` (watch for double-quotes if filename or search phrase has spaces)

Comment: For me in Windows it didn't work without "do":

`for /F %i in ('git rev-list --all foo.rb') do git grep -F bar %i foo.rb`

(watch for double-quotes if filename or search phrase has spaces)

Answer (score 6):

I used 
`git log -S "string" --follow -p "path of file"` which shows the full history of all changes with that string.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by [@Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-nar%C4%99bski) I prefer to regex search for diff that contains 'bar'

```sh
git log -G'bar' -- foo.rb
```

Answer (score 3):

There's an override for git log command (from [manual](http://book.git-scm.com/3_reviewing_history_-_git_log.html)):

```
$ git log Makefile      # commits that modify Makefile
```

So you could use:

```
git log foo.rb | grep "bar"
```

Comment: Thanks, but this just searches the commit history, not the history of the file's source.

Comment: There's actually another override that searches for string data change: git log -S'foo()'     # commits that add or remove any file data matching the string 'foo()'

Comment: You could also try using --full-diff parameter. Logs do not only show the commits history, but the diffs also.

Comment: @DmitriyReznik - apparently `--full-diff` doesn't work (as in, no diff is shown) without `-p`, at least on git 1.7.9.5