# Why git search does not find string

Tags: git, search

I already [used search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47307978/5784831) and also found [another post with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2928584/5784831), but I can't find the following string in my history (using git bash on Windows):

```
$ git log --all -S'paste0(gsub("0",""'
```

And it must have been added somewhere - I think:

[image: V1]

and later

[image]

Any idea what can go wrong? Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a space after the comma in the screenshot, but not in your query.