# Can I check that the diff between two versions of a file solely contains a new prefix that I've added?

Tags: git, version-control, diff

**Background**

As part work to abstract a few classes to one interface, I've had to changes a file which makes use of one of these old classes to now point it to the interface fields.

The file previously would have looked something like this (simplified for example).

```
public class Foo{

    public string RetrieveValue(MyModel model)
    {
        return model.Area.Street.Flat;
    }

    public string RetrieveOtherValue(MyModel model)
    {
        return model.Area.Shop;
    }

}
```

But would now look like this.

```
public class Foo{

    public string RetrieveValue(MyModel model)
    {
        return model.Base_Area.Base_Street.Base_Flat;
    }

    public string RetrieveOtherValue(MyModel model)
    {
        return model.Base_Area.Base_Shop;
    }

}
```

**Question**

Can I check easily that the only change here was the inclusion of `Base_` in various places?

It's easy to see on this scale with a diff tool, but the file big enough that I don't trust just eyeballing it. My source control in use is git but I'm happy to use other tools if necessary.

Ideally I'd like to ignore all sorts of whitespace, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following should get close:

```
git diff --word-diff-regex=. > changes.txt
grep -oP '\+[^\+]+\+' changes.txt | tr -d '\+' | sort -u
```

In the first line, you make a diff which you write to a file.
The second line extracts the changes on character basis and removes the "+". In the end it is sorted and unique values are kept. I applied the above code to your example and got the following result:

```
Base_
```

This even works with more files or files which were changed in other folders. You still get the answer right away - but in case, analysis takes more time.

Comment: You can also add --word-diff=porcelain to have to grep less

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
diff <(git show HEAD~1:/path/to/file) <(sed 's/Base_//' /path/to/file)
```

Change to `HEAD~0` If you have not commited the file yet.

Comment: This does not work in my case. And it would would only work for "Area"?

Comment: Well. Now it is better. Ofcourse, you may have to tune it to fit the exact needs..

Comment: I guess, my answer is closer as you see immediatelly, if there is only one change :-)