# I can't still see my lost files after git reset HEAD{15}

Tags: git

I initially had merge issues and made an unwise decision to do "git merge --abort" and lost all my files. For which I read wrongly that "git reset --hard HEAD~1" would restore the lost files. Unfortunately, it wiped out most of my files. I then read I could do a "git reflog" to get the specific head before I decided to do the "git reset --hard HEAD~1" I then did a "git reset HEAD@{15}" to the specific head. It shows a list of all the files that were deleted. but When I check the folder, the deleted files are not there. And if I do a "git status". it shows me the list of all the files that were deleted by the git reset. How do make the files become visible on the directory?

[Recover from git reset --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard/5788069)

I was hoping after the "git reset HEAD@{15}" the files would become available in the directory

Comment: Perhaps you can find something here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47307978/5784831 if your files were commited, they are somewhere...

Comment: Have you committed you lost changes before `git reset --hard`?

Comment: Yes I did. @akobbs

Comment: Have you tried `git reset --hard HEAD@{15}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution in you case:

`git reset --hard HEAD@{15}`

#### git reset (--mixed) vs git reset --hard

`git reset --hard [commit]` updates *index* (staging area) and your *working directory*

`git reset [commit]` updates *index* (staging area) and doesn't change the *working directory*