# How to stage single lines in git using git bash?

Tags: git

Just create an folder containing an empty `test.txt` file, add and commit it.
Then add the following:

```
new line keep

new line skip

new line bad

new line keep 2
```

Now assume, I only want to keep the first and the last line. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085191/5784831), I should be able to split the single hunk using `git add -i -p test.txt` and the `s` option, but this does not work (and the option is not displayed). Do I miss anything?
The `diff` looks ok:

[image]

---

Problem with [edit in VI](https://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/vi.php): What is wrong? I modified successfully 
[image]

Then I want to quit but
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is very easy to do in `git gui`. Select the file in the staging window. Highlight the line(s) you want then right-click in text area and select "Stage Line For Commit"

For the command line:
Select `e` to manually split hunk. This will bring up a text editor. Change the `+` to a `#`for any lines you don't want to stage.

```
+ new line keep
+
#new line skip
#
#new line bad
#
+new line keep 2
```

Comment: But it does not work in git bash?? BTW: It seems I can not add a linebreak? The result looks like `new line keepnew line keep 2`?

Comment: @Christoph Like you, I value this useful answer but would love to know about the CLI too.

Comment: It looks like you deleted the lines. You want to replace the `+` with a `#`

Answer (score 5):

(This is more a very long comment that needs formatting, than an answer.  See [EncryptedWatermelon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58731238/1256452) for the direct answer.)

The "split" option to `git add -p` only handles the case where a diff hunk has two fused sub-changes:

```
@@ ...
 context
+new1
 context
 context
+new2
 context
```

for instance can be split, but:

```
@@ ...
 context
+new1
+new2
 context
```

cannot be split: it's a single change, not two changes whose contexts adjoined (or overlapped) and hence were fused into one hunk.

To get `git add -p` to apply such a patch, you must turn the patch into instructions to add (and/or delete) only certain lines within the patch.  As the meta-instructions say, this involves *deleting* (or commenting out) added lines that you don't want added after all, and *replacing the minus sign* on lines you don't want deleted.  That is:

```
@@ ...
 context-above
+new1
-old
+new2
 context-below
```

should become:

```
@@ ...
 context-above
+new1
 old
 context-below
```

The result is, as you can see by reading it, a set of instructions that say: *In the original file, find the lines reading `context-above`, then `old`, then `context-below` as the context.  In that region, insert the new line `new1`.*

Several recent versions of Git have problems following correct patch instructions in `git add -p`.  If you hit these particular Git versions, your options are to downgrade Git to one that does not have the bug, upgrade Git to one that has the bug fixed, or—my personal favorite—don't bother with this silly "hack up the patch to make a new patch" approach: just copy the file outside the VCS.

The version control system is a tool-set.  If none of its hammers and saws work on your problem, there's no reason to abuse a screwdriver as a chisel.  Just take the file over to the other work-table, where there's a handy jigsaw or router that makes the job easy, and use that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. May I ask you for a favor? I had a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47307978/5784831) some time ago and I would be still interested in an "answer for the beginner". Git reference is great but in many cases the beginner is lost in the details. Am am fine with the one or two most important use cases...

Comment: Unfortunately, these details really matter a lot. You need to know them to use the Git tool-set effectively. I'll take a stab at it, though.