# How to search github repo code for string with leading ampersand

Tags: github, search

The string "@cuda" probably appears hundreds of times in [this](https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CUDA.jl) particular repo, [ex here](https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CUDA.jl/blob/7dccb1c718eaa268c68b7569cd836e466a28ea44/test/device/array.jl#L65).

I try to search using the search box like this:
[image]

**MWE #1 (searching repo code for string "@cuda"):**

`https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CUDA.jl/search?q=%40cuda&unscoped_q=%40cuda`

Message:

We could not perform this search
Search text is required when searching source code. Searches that use qualifiers only are not allowed. Were you searching for something else?

**MWE #2 (searching repo code for string "\@cuda")** *Maybe the "@" needs to be escaped?*

`https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CUDA.jl/search?q=%5C%40cuda&unscoped_q=%5C%40cuda`

Message:

We could not perform this search
Search text is required when searching source code. Searches that use qualifiers only are not allowed. Were you searching for something else?

Comment: Does that help https://stackoverflow.com/q/47307978/5784831? You can use git.