# Git: How can I determine the filename where a given identifier was added or removed?

Tags: git

I find out that a certain CSS class `.razmatazz` is used in an HTML file, but this identifier is not in any of the present CSS files. That explains the incorrect presentation, which I've been "kicking forward" for some time.

I can find [all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5816177/704972) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4472267/704972) [commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1340245/704972) in which this identifier was either added or deleted by running

```
> git log -S razmatazz --source --all
847d9d8 Thu Jun 25 10:05:07 2018 Joe C helpful commit message.
9384843 Wed May 20 14:10:34 2018 Joe C ever more helpful commit message.
2093483 Mon Apr 15 11:15:51 2018 Joe C yet another great message.
```

but meanwhile I've been merging/unmerging/renaming my CSS files, hence I do not know the CSS filename.

*How can I determine the filename where a given identifier was added or removed?*

Since the "pickaxe" git option doesn't say whether the identifier was added or deleted, I would try both the hashes found and their predecessors

```
git show 847d9d8:/path/to/file
git show 847d9d8^:/path/to/file
git show 9384843:/path/to/file
git show 9384843^:/path/to/file
git show 2093483:/path/to/file
git show 2093483^:/path/to/file
```

to [retrieve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/610315/704972) the missing definition.

Answer (score 1):

`-S` or `-G` can actually by combined with other options :

- `--name-only` and `--name-status` will only list files where said pattern was selected,
- `-p|--patch` will only show you the diff of said files (the complete diff of these files though, it will not limit the diff to only chunks which impact the `-G / -S` search criteria)

---

So : depending on what you want, add `-p` or `--name-status` to your `git log -S razmattaz` command.