# search both history log and files on git, with termux and regexp

Tags: regex, git, search, termux

tried every answer from similar questions:

[How to grep Git commit diffs or contents for a certain word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337320/how-to-grep-git-commit-diffs-or-contents-for-a-certain-word/274502)

[Search all of Git history for a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468361/search-all-of-git-history-for-a-string/274502)

[How to grep (search) committed code in the Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-committed-code-in-the-git-history/274502)

none worked!

would it even be possible to search using [anything other than `git` itself](https://beyondgrep.com/feature-comparison/)?

repository tested: http://cregox.net

## scenario

picture hundreds of markdown files, a dozens of which will have something like this:

```
---
title: lorem ipsum
description: foo, or not foo, it's not even a question
bar: false
```

(in practice, instead of `foo` it was `checklist` and instead of `bar` i wanted `published`)

## expected

```
ag "foo[\s\S]*bar:\ "
```

will search all files with 1 `foo` that happens before the first `bar:`  if they both exist.

all i needed was **that**, applied to git history.

that's it.

but...

## reality

```
git log -G "foo[\s\S]*bar:\ "
```

instead of silversearcher-ag doesn't even work because of `\s`.

i've tried [many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981809/274502) variations of regexp, couldn't find any single one that would work!

so that's something that i'll want to fix at some point, but meanwhile i also tried other alternatives...

```
git log -p -S foo
```

should bring something similar to `rg foo`, but doesn't come even close to be readable and it's way too verbose.

```
git log --name-status --oneline -S foo
```

[this](https://gist.github.com/lyoshenka/8251914) was the closest i could get to the expected results... but it's still too cumbersome.

i give up digging for now.

Comment: is asking for regex help to solve his problem so restoring `regex` tag

Comment: What do you mean by "history log"? Is "ag" [this searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)?

Comment: @torek i meant git log commit messages history. yes, it's the silver searcher. also mentioned rip grep.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to use an external searcher on Git log messages: the only way to do that is to have Git extract each commit to some plain-text file. This is because commits are, internally, Git objects, and all Git objects are just these read-only, compressed, de-duplicated data blocks. (Commits are never duplicates so the de-duplication side effect is largely irrelevant here, except in terms of delta compression in pack files.) It's even more difficult to search commit diffs as Git has to *generate* those diffs from scratch every time you have Git compare two commits.

Comment: If you do wish to do something like that, consider running `git log -m -p`, redirecting the output to a file, and then using your external searcher on the file. It's going to be messy.

Comment: @torek thanks for the input! seems like it's a better idea to figure out what could be wrong in my end... i was thinking it could be unsupported operations by git.

Answer (score 2):

With `git log` regex following should work for you to match across the lines:

```
git log --name-status --oneline -G 'foo(\S|\s)+bar:\s'
```

Comment: nope. still getting the same deprecation warning for the regex... and empty results. wonder if there's something broken with my termux now.

Comment: Hmm strange as that is working fine on my `git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)`