# Git grep across multiple repositories in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, git, grep

I have a list of bitbucket repositories on a server:

```
[user@lonapdbitbucket1 repositories]$ ls
1039 1044 1059 2165 2656 3958 3958 9284 9274 8274 7264 7263 8274
```

If I cd into one of these repositories and run git grep, to search for Ansible encryption strings, then it works fine - git grep manages to find an Ansible encryption string:

```
[user@lonapdbitbucket1 repositories]$ cd 1044 
[user@lonapdbitbucket1 repositories]$ git grep -P '\$ANSIBLE_VAULT;[0-9]\.[0-];AES256' $(git rev-list --all)
```

To do this across multiple repos, I thought to convert it into a bash script:

```
# secret_scan.sh
repos_root=/var/lib/docker/volumes/bitbucket/_data/shared/data/repositories
git_grep_cmd=git grep -P '\$ANSIBLE_VAULT;[0-9]\.[0-];AES256' $(git rev-list --all)
for dir in ./*
do
    # below line is just to clean up the directory string
    repo_dir="$(d{dir#./}"
    cd "${repos_root}${repo_dir}"; \
    eval "git_grep_cmd"
done
```

Unfortunately, this does not work:

```
[user@lonapdbitbucket1 repositories]$ ./secret_scan.sh
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/lib)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
[user@lonapdbitbucket1 repositories]$ _
```

Would anyone be able to suggest a solution here, to essentially cd into multiple repositories and then run git grep on each, replicating results as if i were doing it on the command line?

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: Don't store commands in variables. Variables are for data, not executable code. If you need to store executable code, use a function (or maybe an array), but in this case I'd just skip storing it. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) BTW, the immediate problem is that your syntax for storing the command is all wrong, you need another layer of quoting/escaping, but fixing that is messy. Just don't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with eval and repo_dir. This should be as simple as:

```
repos_root=/var/lib/docker/volumes/bitbucket/_data/shared/data/repositories
for dir in *
do
    cd "$repos_root$dir";
    git grep -P '\$ANSIBLE_VAULT;[0-9]\.[0-];AES256' $(git rev-list --all)
done
```

Since your `repos_root` is absolute, you don't need to take care of returning to the original directory.

But I'm sceptical that `git rev-list --all` can be substituted, its output will be huge. Are you trying to find the string in ALL commits? To search the full history for a string, check [Search all of Git history for a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468361/search-all-of-git-history-for-a-string) and [How to grep Git commit diffs or contents for a certain word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337320/how-to-grep-git-commit-diffs-or-contents-for-a-certain-word)