# Remove all text before colon

Tags: r, unix, replace, sed, awk

I have a file containing a certain number of lines. Each line looks like this:

```
TF_list_to_test10004/Nus_k0.345_t0.1_e0.1.adj:PKMYT1
```

I would like to remove all before ":" character in order  to retain only PKMYT1 that is a gene name. 
Since I'm not an expert in regex scripting can anyone help me to do this using Unix (sed or awk) or in R?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Here are two ways of doing it in R:

```
foo <- "TF_list_to_test10004/Nus_k0.345_t0.1_e0.1.adj:PKMYT1"

# Remove all before and up to ":":
gsub(".*:","",foo)

# Extract everything behind ":":
regmatches(foo,gregexpr("(?<=:).*",foo,perl=TRUE))
```

Comment: Also, if any of the gene names might themselves self contain a `:`, you could match and replace up to the *first* `:` using  `gsub("^[^:]*:", "", foo)`

Comment: `gsub()` allows you to use "regular expressions".  In the answer above, the `.` means wildcard (any character), the `*` means "zero or more occurences", and then the `:` is the symbol we're interested in stopping at.  If, say, you wanted to remove all before a `-`, you could replace the colon with one.  After the `".*:",` argument, you're putting your replacement for whatever appears before the `:`,  so be sure to to avoid adding an erroneous space between the quotes there.

Answer (score 25):

A simple regular expression used with `gsub()`:

```
x <- "TF_list_to_test10004/Nus_k0.345_t0.1_e0.1.adj:PKMYT1"
gsub(".*:", "", x)
"PKMYT1"
```

See `?regex` or `?gsub` for more help.

Answer (score 10):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/.*://' < your_input_file > output_file
```

This will replace anything followed by a colon with nothing, so it'll remove everything up to and including the last colon on each line ([because `*` is greedy by default](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq5.html#s5.4)).

As per Josh O'Brien's comment, if you wanted to only replace up to and including the first colon, do this:

```
sed "s/[^:]*://"
```

That will match anything that isn't a colon, followed by one colon, and replace with nothing.

Note that for both of these patterns they'll stop on the first match on each line.  If you want to make a replace happen for every match on a line, add the ['`g`' (global)](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-6) option to the end of the command.

Also note that on linux (but not on OSX) you can edit a file in-place with `-i` eg:

```
sed -i 's/.*://' your_file
```

Answer (score 10):

There are certainly more than 2 ways in R.  Here's another.

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(foo, ':', fixed = TRUE), '[', 2))
```

If the string has a constant length I imagine `substr` would be faster than this or regex methods.

Comment: I suspect this may be the fastest R solution given. +1

Answer (score 10):

Solution using `str_remove` from the `stringr` package:

```
str_remove("TF_list_to_test10004/Nus_k0.345_t0.1_e0.1.adj:PKMYT1", ".*:")
[1] "PKMYT1"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk -F: '{print $2}' /your/file
```

Answer (score 6):

Some very simple move that I missed from the best response @Sacha Epskamp was to use the sub function, in this case to take everything before the ":"(instead of removing it), so it was very simple:

```
foo <- "TF_list_to_test10004/Nus_k0.345_t0.1_e0.1.adj:PKMYT1"

# 1st, as she did to remove all before and up to ":":
gsub(".*:","",foo)

# 2nd, to keep everything before and up to ":": 
gsub(":.*","",foo)
```

Basically, the same thing, just change the ":" position inside the sub argument. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU `coreutils` available use `cut`:

```
cut -d: -f2 infile
```

Answer (score 2):

I was working on a similar issue. John's and Josh O'Brien's advice did the trick. I started with this tibble:

```
library(dplyr)
my_tibble <- tibble(Col1=c("ABC:Content","BCDE:MoreContent","FG:Conent:with:colons"))
```

It looks like:

```
  | Col1 
1 | ABC:Content 
2 | BCDE:MoreContent 
3 | FG:Content:with:colons
```

I needed to create this tibble:

```
  | Col1                  | Col2 | Col3 
1 | ABC:Content           | ABC  | Content 
2 | BCDE:MoreContent      | BCDE | MoreContent 
3 | FG:Content:with:colons| FG   | Content:with:colons
```

And did so with this code (R version 3.4.2).

```
my_tibble2 <- mutate(my_tibble
        ,Col2 = unlist(lapply(strsplit(Col1, ':',fixed = TRUE), '[', 1))
        ,Col3 = gsub("^[^:]*:", "", Col1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are 2 equivalent solutions:

The first uses perl's `-a` autosplit feature to split each line into fields using `:`, populate the `F` fields array, and print the 2nd field `$F[1]` (counted starting from field 0)

```
perl -F: -lane 'print $F[1]' file
```

The second uses a regular expression to substitute `s///` from `^` the beginning of the line, `.*:` any characters ending with a colon, with nothing

```
perl -pe 's/^.*://' file
```