# Error when exporting dataframe to text file in R

Tags: r, export

I am trying to write a dataframe in R to a text file, however it is returning to following error:

```
Error in if (inherits(X[[j]], "data.frame") && ncol(xj) > 1L)
             X[[j]] <- as.matrix(X[[j]]) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I used the following command for the export:

```
write.table(df, file ='dfname.txt', sep='\t' )
```

I have no idea what the problem could stem from. As far as "missing data where TRUE/FALSE is needed", I have only one column which contains TRUE/FALSE values, and none of these values are missing.

Contents of the dataframe:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   776 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ Age         : Factor w/ 4 levels "","A","J","SA": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Sex         : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Rep         : Factor w/ 11 levels "L","NR","NRF",..: 1 1 4 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ FA          : num  61.5 62.5 60.5 61 59.5 59.5 59.1 59.2 59.8 59.9 ...
 $ Mass        : num  20 19 16.5 17.5 NA 14 NA 23 19 18.5 ...
 $ Vir1        : num  999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 ...
 $ Vir2        : num  999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 ...
 $ Vir3        : num  40 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 ...
 $ Location    : Factor w/ 4 levels "Loc1",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Site        : Factor w/ 6 levels "A","B","C",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Date        : Date, format: "2010-08-30" "2010-08-30" ...
 $ Record      : int  35 34 39 49 69 38 145 112 125 140 ...
 $ SampleID    : Factor w/ 776 levels "AT1-A-F1","AT1-A-F10",..: 525 524 527 528
                                                                 529 526 111 78
                                                                 88 110 ...
 $ Vir1Inc     : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ Month       :'data.frame':   776 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Dates: Date, format: "2010-08-30" "2010-08-30" ...
  ..$ Month: Factor w/ 19 levels "Apr-2011","Aug-2010",..: 2 2 2 2 
                                                           2 2 18 18 18 18 ...
```

I hope I've given enough/the right information ...

Many thanks,
Heather

Comment: I think you get an error because  Your data.frame contains a nested data.frame names Month...

Comment: @agstudy the help file says `write.table` can handle nested dataframes.  My guess is that something's fouled up and the `&& ncol(xj)` code given in the error message is trying to process a non-matrix, hence `ncolxj)` returns `NULL`, and `R` hates "NULL" in a logical operation.

Comment: Anyway, the obvious plan of attack is to try `write.table` on a portion of `df` , after removing candidate "bad" elements, and see which element is the culprit.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft You can see my example.

Comment: Yup -- looks like the documentation for `write.table` is incomplete.  It can handle columns which are lists, but not nested lists.

Comment: Thank you.. Your nested data frame and error statement was helpful.. Thanks

Comment: I met this issue with `write.table` when I created a data frame from a matrix via `as.data.frame`. The columns are created as lists of one-item lists then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution by agstudy provides a great quick fix, but there is a  **simple alternative/general solution** for which you do not have to specify the element(s) in your data.frame that was(were) nested:

The following bit is just copied from [agstudy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17296895/4798582) to obtain the nested data.frame `dd`:

```
Month=data.frame(Dates= as.Date("2003-02-01") + 1:15,
                 Month=gl(12,2,15))
dd <- data.frame(Age=1:15)
dd$Month <- Month
```

You can use [akhilsbehl's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533691/asb) `LinearizeNestedList()` function (which mrdwab made available [here](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/4205477)) to flatten (or linearize) the nested levels:

```
library(devtools)
source_gist(4205477) #loads the function

ddf <- LinearizeNestedList(dd, LinearizeDataFrames = TRUE) 
# ddf is now a list with two elements (Age and Month)

ddf <- LinearizeNestedList(ddf, LinearizeDataFrames = TRUE) 
# ddf is now a list with 3 elements (Age, `Month/Dates` and `Month/Month`)

ddf <- as.data.frame.list(ddf)
# transforms the flattened/linearized list into a data.frame
```

`ddf` is now a data.frame without nesting. However, it's column names still reflect the nested structure:

```
names(ddf)
[1] "Age"         "Month.Dates" "Month.Month"
```

If you want to change this (in this case it seems redundant to have `Month.` written before `Dates`, for example) you can use `gsub` and [some regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12297934/4798582) that I copied from Sacha Epskamp to remove all text in the column names before the `.`.

```
names(ddf) <- gsub(".*\\.","",names(ddf))  
names(ddf)
[1] "Age"   "Dates" "Month"
```

The only thing left now is exporting the data.frame as usual:

```
write.table(ddf, file="test.txt")
```

Answer (score 6):

An example to reproduce the error. I create a nested data.frame:

```
Month=data.frame(Dates= as.Date("2003-02-01") + 1:15,
                 Month=gl(12,2,15))
dd <- data.frame(Age=1:15)
dd$Month <- Month
str(dd)
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Age  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Month:'data.frame':  15 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Dates: Date, format: "2003-02-02" "2003-02-03" "2003-02-04" ...
  ..$ Month: Factor w/ 12 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
```

No I try to save it , I reproduce the error :

```
write.table(dd)
Error in if (inherits(X[[j]], "data.frame") && ncol(xj) > 1L) 
    X[[j]] <- as.matrix(X[[j]]) :  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Without inverstigating, one option to remove the nested `data.frame`:

```
write.table(data.frame(subset(dd,select=-c(Month)),unclass(dd$Month)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use the "flatten" function from the jsonlite package to flatten the dataframe before export.  It achieves the same result of the other functions mentioned and is much easier to implement.

`jsonlite::flatten`

https://rdrr.io/cran/jsonlite/man/flatten.html

Comment: jsonlite::flatten works really well to flatten a nested data frame. But the link you provided is dead.