# Remove part of col names in list of data frames - R

Tags: r, regex, list, dataframe

In this dummy list of data frames, all column names have a prefix followed by an underscore. Each data frame in the list has a different prefix, but they all include an underscore.

How can I remove the underscore and the text before it in the column names of all data frames in the list? I can do it individually, but my real list contains many more data frames. Thank you

```
#add diferent prefixes to all col names
colnames(iris)<-paste('iris_',colnames(iris), sep='')

colnames(mtcars)<-paste('mt_',colnames(mtcars), sep='')

colnames(ToothGrowth)<-paste('TG_',colnames(ToothGrowth), sep='')

#create list of data frames

mylist<-list(iris, mtcars, ToothGrowth)

#name elements of list

names(mylist)<-c('iris','mtcars','ToothGrowth')

#remove prefix from colnames individually for each data frame

colnames(mylist['iris']$iris)<-sub('[^.]+\\_', '', colnames(mylist['iris']$iris))
```

Comment: You just need to do this for each element of the list. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297859/remove-all-text-before-colon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop through the `list`, remove the prefix of the column names with `sub`, and set the names with `setNames`

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) setNames(x, sub("^[^_]*_", "", names(x))))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, loop through the `list` with `map` and remove the substring of the column names with `str_remove` inside `rename_all`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(mylist, ~  .x %>% 
                  rename_all(~ str_remove(.x, "^[^_]*_")))
```