# Delete part of column name for multiple columns

Tags: r, rename, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I am cleaning my data in a tibble format with tidyverse. I want to get rid of prefix in column names which were assigned by system, eg:

```
x <- c("XYZ.date", "XYZ.region", "XYZ.region.europe.western").
```

There are not many distinct prefixes, BUT they are not always the same length.I know I can rename them one by one with *rename* function, but is there a way to get rid of them all at once?

It is not a problem to do a list of them.

Comment: hi,what i understand is you want to rename or remove pattern from column, then use ```gsub``` will help

Comment: Would you have a situation where you have "XYZ_date" and "JWNDI_date"? in other words, are there situations where the column name would be the same following prefix removal? Lastly, are all the prefixes separated by an "_"?

Comment: Possible duplicate, related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12297859/680068

Comment: If the prefix ("XYZ") is fixed then simply `substring(x, 5)` should do.

Answer (score 3):

```
foo <- function(x) gsub("^[^_]*_", "", x)

df %>%
    rename_all(foo)
```

So, here I write a function that says remove everything from a string up to the underscore ("_") and then apply this function to all the names.

Comment: i misled you. the names looks like XYZ.date, XYZ.region. BUT they can have more dots later, like: XYZ.region.europe.western

Answer (score 2):

This replaces each occurrence of all characters up to and including underscore with the empty string and then makes the result unique. We can optionally remove `%>% make.unique` in the first case or `%>% as_tibble(.name_repair = "unique")` in the second case if it is known that the names will be unique anyways.

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% rename_all(~ sub(".*_", "", .x) %>% make.unique)
```

or this which disambiguates the names in a slightly different manner.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
DF %>% rename_all(~ sub(".*_", "", .x)) %>% as_tibble(.name_repair = "unique")
```

### Example

For example, using the first case above add prefixes to each name of the built in `anscombe` creating `DF` and apply the above to that in the last line of code below.

```
# set up a test data frame using builtin anscombe
DF <- setNames(anscombe, sub("(.)(.)", "\\1_\\2", names(anscombe)))
names(DF)
## [1] "x_1" "x_2" "x_3" "x_4" "y_1" "y_2" "y_3" "y_4"

DF %>% rename_all(~ sub(".*_", "", .x) %>% make.unique)
##     1  2  3  4   1.1  2.1   3.1   4.1
## 1  10 10 10  8  8.04 9.14  7.46  6.58
## 2   8  8  8  8  6.95 8.14  6.77  5.76
## ...etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, replacing a 3 character alphanumeric prefix followed by an underscore:

```r
colnames(df) <- gsub("^[0-9A-Za-z]{3}_", "", colnames(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to do it

```r
df <- cbind(1,1:4)
colnames(df) <- c("x","Y")
colnames(df) <- paste("Sub", colnames(df), sep = "_")
df
#>      Sub_x Sub_Y
#> [1,]     1     1
#> [2,]     1     2
#> [3,]     1     3
#> [4,]     1     4
colnames(df)<-sub("^[^_]*_","",colnames(df))
df
#>      x Y
#> [1,] 1 1
#> [2,] 1 2
#> [3,] 1 3
#> [4,] 1 4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>