# How to remove part of string before a dot in R

Tags: r, dplyr, replace

I have a column whose pattern of data is similar to the one here reported:

```
strings = c('AIR:MT.S:R-V:Q', 
            'AIR:MT.T:P-V:Q')
```

I am looking for a function I can apply in a way that with dplyr I can remove all the part before the `.` Thus, the wanted output would be like this:

```
S:R-V:Q
T:P-V:Q
```

How it be that possible to do

Comment: You could `mutate` with `sub`. Is this what you want: `mutate(strings = sub("^[^\\.]+\\.", "", strings))`?

Comment: Split and get 2nd item, use regex, or using stringr `word(strings, 2, sep = fixed("."))`.

Comment: Another near-duplicate may be this question, if you simply change to period from colon: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297859/remove-all-text-before-colon

Comment: Here are some possibilities: `sub("\\..*", "", strings)` or `read.table(text = strings, comment.char = ".")[[1]]` or `scan(text = strings, what = "", comment.char = ".", quiet = TRUE)`