# How to find git commits in the repository by commit message?

Tags: git

We have recently converted our SVN repositories to GIT. It seems that we lost some commits by this conversion and would like to verify this.

So we would like to find a matching git commit for each svn commit to check whether the conversion has actually occured.

`$ git log|grep "some partial commit message"` will not suffice as it only walks through direct ancenstors and ignores branches that are not direct ancestors.

`$ git show <commit-hash>` will not work as svn doesn't have sha1sums.

the closest thing I found was: `$  git reflog show --all  --grep="releasenotes"|xargs git show --shortstat` however this doesn't seem to completely work as it seems to grep in more places than just the commit message (We got a false positive).

I also tried to use this: `$ git rev-list --all|xargs -n1 bash -c 'git show|head -n10'|grep -i release`

basically I'm lacking a good method to print the commit message without the diffs.

[EDIT]

I'm not exactly sure but I guess this should list all commit messages in the repository.

```
git rev-list --all|xargs -n1 git log -n1
```

Comment: Reading the manpage for git-log will help: you can use something like `git log --all --format=<format> | grep <grep options>`, where  `<format>` would be something like "SHA - commit message" as detailed by the man page

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just use the `--all` option for `git log`

```
git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate | grep "message"
```

Which is equivalent to

```
git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate --grep "message"
```

Or if you would prefer to have the context and don't have a lot of commits you might want to do something like

```
git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate | less
/ message
```

And that way you can see *where* your commits are with respect to other commits.

Comment: More complete answer than mine. +1

Answer (score 9):

You could use the `--grep` option of [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
$ git log --all --grep=word
```

See "[How to grep git commits for a certain word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337320/how-to-grep-git-commits-for-a-certain-word)": this is for grepping commit *messages*.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use GUI.

```
gitk
```

It will open a GUI, then write your commit message in **containing box**, and hit enter key.

It will show all matching commits with highlighted.