# Git: When did a branch got merged into master?

Tags: git, git-merge

How do I know when a branch (or a commit) was merged into another branch?
For example - given I have branch1 and master and, sometime in the past, branch1 was merged into master, how can I know when a specific commit was introduced into the main branch?
As far as Git cares, once the commit is reachable from master, it's there.

See example (windows) script to illustrate the problem:

```
rd .git /s /q
del data.txt

git init

echo 1 > data.txt
git add data.txt
git commit -m initial_commit_master

git checkout -b branch1
echo 2 > data.txt
git add data.txt
git commit -m commit_in_branch1

git checkout master
git merge branch1

echo 3 > data.txt
git add data.txt
git commit -m 2nd_commit_master
```

How do I recognize that "2" (in data.txt) came from branch "branch1" and the earliest point it was joined to master?

Edit 1: An example use case - since we deploy from master, I'm interested to know when a specific change was actually introduced to production. I know it's in master *now* ("2" was in master at some point) - but I don't know when it was put into master because all I see is the image today, not the image that was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking around to find something similar - get the timestamp of when a change was pulled/merged into your current branch. I wanted this info so that I could see when exactly I moved (pulled/merged) some changes to the master branch of a production environment. And this is what I found is useful:

Command:
`git reflog show --date=default`

Output:

`5c4f140 HEAD@{Mon Aug 10 05:36:24 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward
1ba6e4e HEAD@{Wed Aug 5 14:40:50 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward
05382e4 HEAD@{Wed Jul 22 12:27:20 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward
bad194c HEAD@{Wed Jul 22 09:54:01 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward
016f6cb HEAD@{Sat Jul 18 04:53:56 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward
b4839d3 HEAD@{Mon Jul 6 07:35:23 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward`

Basically it shows you the commit id, and when it was merged into the current system (local).

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer is : you can't do it in a 100% reliable way. For example, you may delete the `branch1` branch, and git won't keep any trace of the commit's original branch.

That being said :

You can find the commit(s) which introduced a `"2"` in `data.txt`, using `git log -Sword` :

```
git log -S2 -- data.txt
```

Once you have targeted the commit you are looking for, you can find the branches (that still exist) which contain the given commit :

```
git branch --contains <hash>
```

references :
[How to grep Git commit diffs or contents for a certain word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337320/how-to-grep-git-commit-diffs-or-contents-for-a-certain-word)
[How to list branches that contain a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit)

Comment: I know these :). Since we deploy from master, I'm interested to know when a specific change was actually introduced to production. I know it's in master _now_ - but I don't know when it was put into master.

Answer (score 1):

[This GitHub repo](https://github.com/mhagger/git-when-merged) does what you need.