# Searching git commits for a particular change

Tags: git

I'm working on one particular branch in my git repo and notice a piece of code that I thought I changed. Perhaps the change is on another branch that hasn't been merged into `master` or the current branch on which I am working. How do I search the whole repository, including all branches, for a particular change to one source code file?

Comment: There may well be a more elegant solution, but you could just grep the output of `git log --all --stat`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try and use the pickaxe (`-S`) or regexp (`-G`) options of [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

```
git log --all -Schange -- path/to/change
```

(replace change by a keyword you know is representing your particular change)

See "[How to grep (search) committed code in the git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928721/6309)"

As I mentioned:

> this looks for **differences that introduce or remove an instance of `<string>`**.
>   It usually means "revisions where you added or removed line with '`change`'".

Add the `--all` in order to search in all branches.

To get the branch(es) those commits are part on, you can use:

```
git branch --contains SHA1
```

(as I mentioned in "[How to list branches that contain a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419637/6309)")

Comment: Okay, that's definitely helpful. However, it only shows the commits in the current branch. My primary problem is that the change my not occur on the current branch, if I actually committed it at all. How can I search every branch in my repo?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that would be the `--all` option. I have edited the answer.

Comment: One last thing: this gives me the commit message, including the SHA hash. Now how do I get the branch(es) this commit is on?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have edited the answer (referencing an older answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1419637/6309)

Comment: Thanks. I tried asking this as a new question, but it was so short that it didn't pass the quality standards filter.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice no problem: that remains in the same context as your original question, so I put the answer in the same place.

Comment: Finally, how do I make `git log` just give me the hash so I can do this all in one line (i.e. pass the hash directly to `git branch --contains`)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice actually, maybe adding `--decorate` to the `git log` command would be enough to show the branches? (as in http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/07/git-tips/

Comment: From what I can tell `--decorate` only adds a branch name to the head commit of the branch.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: @KansaiRobot `git log --all -Schange -- path/to/change` mentioned in the answer is a concrete example. Other concrete examples: http://www.philandstuff.com/2014/02/09/git-pickaxe.html, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1340245/6309, https://gitfu.wordpress.com/2008/06/03/the-pickaxe-finding-changes-was-never-easier/, https://remireuvekamp.nl/blog/the-git-pickaxe.html