# git - Search when a keyword first occur in a file or dir

Tags: git

There is a `log/` dir in git repo, and under it resides a file called `history.txt`.

I want to know when the keyword `linux programming` first occur in `history.txt` or `log/`, means find the date of the first commit contain the keyword.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can use the `find` command, although it depends on what os you are.

Comment: @TomTsagk The find command can only search the current working dir, right? It can't search history of git I think.

Comment: I believe you can specify another directory, you can try `man find`.

Comment: @TomTsagk By `current working dir`, I mean in the sense of git, e.g in git you can check out different branch or commit, which might has different content. Thus `find` command could find a specific commit, but it can't search the whole history & tell when that change occur.

Comment: oooh well can't you search on `history.txt` as you said in your question? I'm new at `git` and I'm not sure how old commits (or snapshots) are saved. I see there is already an answer and seems good (didn't know git had internal command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [pickaxe search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1340245/6309)

```
git log -S"linux programming" -- log/
```

Take the oldest commit returned by that command (`| tail -1`), and you will get your date.

Comment: Yeah, I check the `-S` option of `git log`, that's what I need, git is amazing!