# search for a commit where a string first introduced in a file (including commits in deleted branch)

Tags: git, git-log

I'm searching for a commit where a string first introduced in a file .
This commit can be in master or **any branch** .

I'm searching for a commit where string  "**public static String BUILD = "0829_12"**" was introduced in file '**version.java**'

The prbolem is that the branch where this commit occurred was **deleted**.

How can I search for that ?

Comment: Note that when using these -S and -G `git log` options and you want to find where it *first occurred*, just take the last one shown (since they're sorted into reverse date order by default). Use `--branches` or `--all` to search from all branches or all references.

Comment: I forgot to add that i need to search commits of deleted branch also

Comment: If the branch name is gone, the commits are either reachable by another name, or also gone. If they are reachable by tag or remote-tracking-branch name, `--all` will find them. If they are truly gone, they're *gone*.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337320/how-to-grep-git-commit-diffs-or-contents-for-a-certain-word for searching. But see earlier comment for "gone".

Answer (score 1):

If the commit has not been removed, you can run:

```
# If you know where the commit lives
git checkout branch_where_the_commit_lives
git log -S 'public static String BUILD = "0829_12"' -p path/to/version.java

# If you don't know, you should add --all to the previous command and run it from any branch
git log --all -S 'public static String BUILD = "0829_12"' -p path/to/version.java
```