# How can I filter git log to show a list of specific revisions/commits?

Tags: git, revision-history

Let's say I have several commits, and I know their revision IDs:

- aaaaaa
- bbbbbb
- cccccc
- dddddd

These commits are not consecutive, and aren't related to each other from git's perspective.

How can I output information about all of these commits in a list with a single command?

Comment: How about `git log` and `grep` ?

Comment: @ckruczek Well, first of all, I'm on Windows. Second of all, the git log output is multiline, so grep will not return all the information I want about every commit.

Comment: Well, I think you have to elaborate your question more. You said you want to have the output in a list, now you are stating you want in one-line. So what do you want ? Additionally, if you are on Windows there is a git bash as well and you can fire the `git log` command with a [grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337320/how-to-grep-git-commit-diffs-or-contents-for-a-certain-word) command as well. So please update your question with more informations.

Comment: @ckruczek I never said I wanted the ouput in one line. I am saying if I use grep, it will return only the matched lines... which will contain the revision ID, but no title, date, author, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `git show`:

`git show aaaaaaa bbbbbb cccccc dddddd`

You can use the `--pretty=format:...` to change the output and display each information you want of each commit on one line.
Also `--no-patch` (or `-s`) to avoid displaying patch.

`git show --no-patch --pretty='format:%h %aN %ad %s' aaaaaaa bbbbbb cccccc dddddd`

Documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show

Comment: OK, this works, but for some reason it shows the full commit with file changes, even when I do this: `git show --format=short aaaaaa`. Any ideas?

Comment: What worked for me is `git show -s aaaaaa bbbbbb`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
git show -s aaaaaa bbbbbb cccccc dddddd
```