# File names only using Git grep

Tags: git, grep

I want to look only at distinct files which have a certain word in their text.

```
current_directory$ git grep 'word'
```

shows each line of the file which has a matching word.

So I tried this

```
current_directory$ git grep 'word' -- files-with-matches
current_directory$ git grep 'word' -- name-only
```

But it doesn't show any output.

Also, how can I count the total occurrences of 'word' in all files?

Comment: It’s `--files-with-matches`. No space after the `--`.

Comment: @Ryan current_directory$ git grep 'word' --files-with-matches fatal: bad flag '--files-with-matches' used after filename

Comment: Oh, you also have to put options before non-options. `git grep --files-with-matches 'word'`

Comment: You don't need that silly long name there is a short option `grep -l 'word'` option. And if you want to opposite use `grep -L 'word'`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The error message helps:

```
$ git grep 'foo' --files-with-matches
fatal: option '--files-with-matches' must come before non-option arguments

$ git grep --files-with-matches 'foo'
<list of matching files>
```

To count the words, this is how I'd do it with [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) (I am not sure if `git grep` has the relevant options):

```
$ grep --exclude-dir=.git -RowF 'foo' | wc -l
717
```

From `man grep`:

> -R, --dereference-recursive 
> Read all files under each directory, recursively.  Follow all symbolic links, unlike -r.
>
> -o, --only-matching 
> Print  only  the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output
> line.
>
> -w, --word-regexp 
> Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words. The test is that the matching
> substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.
> Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character. 
> Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
>
> -F, --fixed-strings 
> Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated  by  newlines,
> any of which is to be matched.
>
> --exclude-dir=DIR 
> Exclude directories matching the pattern DIR from recursive searches.

Comment: (On [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa), 'grep' is GNU grep (version 3.4).)

Answer (score 6):

```
git grep --files-with-matches 'bar'
```

"--files-with-matches" needs to be before your search string