# How to search commit history?

Tags: github

Is there any way to find when the function "_make_parser_function" was introduced in the file pandas/pandas/io/parsers.py?

I tried to search within commit history, but could not find the exact date on which this change was introduced. I guess this function was not available in older versions of pandas.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commits/71334472766fc95e7dc828dce2bfe798f6bb19dc?before=71334472766fc95e7dc828dce2bfe798f6bb19dc+35&path%5B%5D=pandas&path%5B%5D=io&path%5B%5D=parsers.py

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to grep Git commit diffs or contents for a certain word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337320/how-to-grep-git-commit-diffs-or-contents-for-a-certain-word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `-L` option

```sh
# git log -L :myfunction:path/to/myfile.c
git log -L :_make_parser_function:pandas/io/parsers.py
```