# Git equivalent of 'hg grep --all'

Tags: git

When needing to find revisions that have a code change, in a Mercurial repository, one can use the command `hg grep --all '<pattern>'` and get a pretty, colored output in the following format:

```
# filename : revision : +/- : line in file
filename.ext:100:+:The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
filename.ext:100:-:Teh quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
filename.ext:95:+:Teh quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
filename.ext:95:-:Teh quick brown fox jumped over the lazy doge.
```

I was wondering if there was a way to get output similar to this in a Git repository.

**Edit:** The closest I've been able to get to is the following:

```
> git rev-list --all | xargs git grep <pattern>

deadbe..ef6543:filename.ext:The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
deadbe..ef1324:filename.ext:Teh quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
deadbe..ef243a:filename.ext:Teh quick brown fox jumped over the lazy doge.
```

Which I found from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39701177

**Edit:** I have been continuing to work and research this.  As it stands right now, I think there is no "out-of-the-box" solution to be able to accomplish this.  I now think the only way to achieve this is to build a script, or string together some complicated commands, and maybe store them as an alias.

Comment: Sounds like you want the "pickaxe". See the docs for `git log`.

Comment: @matt I've tried the pickaxe method, with both `-G` and `-S` and such, but all it does is return the log, not the actual code changes.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I did find one command on that page that produces something similar to what I am looking for.  I updated my post to show reflect that.

Comment: See [alias `grep-all`](https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias/blob/bf490080764f84d54dbd237920902d27c4b13e8f/gitalias.txt#L457) from [Git Alias](http://www.gitalias.com/); full disclosure: I am a contributor.

Comment: The pickaxe is what you want, ask log to show you the patch. `git log --all -pS pattern` (or `-pG` if you're after any change that mentions that at all).

Comment: So, you want some tool that will scrape just the specific text you want from pickaxe's patch output? I don't know of one, just `/pattern/` in the pager works for me, but a diff scanner's not that hard to write.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+grep+all+revisions

Comment: You weren't the only person to ask about this today, so I wrote [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65204346/1290731). Does that help?