# How to search in commit messages using command line?

Tags: git, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search through all commits in the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746684/how-to-search-through-all-commits-in-the-repository)

Is there a way to search through commit headers using the command line?

Comment: This is not really a duplicate, the other question asks about dangling commits while **this one does not**. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Ah. But this is a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124914/how-to-search-a-git-repository-by-commit-message). While this one is the older question, the newer one has better answers imho. I wish I could revoke my vote to reopen.

Comment: Don't forget to use `--all` to search in non-ancestor commits :}

Answer (score 628, accepted):

```
git log --grep=<pattern>
    Limit the commits output to ones with log message that matches the 
    specified pattern (regular expression).
```

from [`git help log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---grepltpatterngt).

Comment: I think this answer is partially wrong, because the `--grep` option searches the whole commit message, instead of just the header.

@czchen's answer is more correct, in this case.

Comment: except for that fact that czchen's answer requires the use of an external grep utility

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot, before that I used ack-grep.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question about headers specifically, but it did answer mine about commit messages in general - and not only mine, since it's #1 link in google for "git search commit messages"

Comment: Another benefit of this answer is that you can do things like `git log --name-only --grep=foo` if you want more information.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that this will only search your _local_ repository.

Comment: Is there a way to highlight the pattern?

Comment: For those who might make the same mistake that I made: **This DOES work on Windows too!**, so don't look further down for Windows answers. :)

Answer (score 245):

```
git log --oneline | grep PATTERN
```

Comment: Won't this miss commits with the PATTERN in the commit message's lines other than the first?

Comment: requires grep to be available, i.e. this is a linux / git bash specific solution (unless you've installed grep on windows)

Comment: If you're on windows, or some other env. without `grep`, combine both answers: `git log --oneline --grep=PATTERN`

Comment: @tutuDajuju no, the line breaks are just replaced with spaces

Comment: another point to note is that if you are using strings within commit messages don't forget to add the ignore case flag like this in end.         `git log --oneline | grep PATTERN -i`