# How to search a Git repository by commit message?

Tags: git, git-log

I checked some source code into GIT with the commit message "Build 0051".

However, I can't seem to find that source code any more - how do I extract this source from the GIT repository, using the command line?

**Update**

1. Checked in versions 0043, 0044, 0045 and 0046 using SmartGIT.
2. Checked out 0043, and checked in versions up to 0051 on a different branch.
3. Checked out 0043 again.
4. Now, 0051 has disappeared.

**Update**

The source code is definitely there, now its a matter of checking it out:

```
C:\Source>git log -g --grep="0052"
commit 77b1f718d19e5cf46e2fab8405a9a0859c9c2889
Reflog: HEAD@{10} (unknown <Mike@.(none)>)
Reflog message: commit: 20110819 - 1724 - GL: Intermediate version. File version:  v0.5.0 build 0052.
Author: unknown <Mike@.(none)>
Date:   Fri Aug 19 17:24:51 2011 +0100

    20110819 - 1724 - GL: Intermediate version. File version: v0.5.0 build 0052.

C:\Source>
```

Comment: See also: [How to search through all commits in the repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746684/how-to-search-through-all-commits-in-the-repository)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122628/how-to-search-for-a-commit-message-in-github

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to grep git commits for a certain word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337320/how-to-grep-git-commits-for-a-certain-word)

Answer (score 1848, accepted):

To search the commit log (across all branches) for the given text:

```
git log --all --grep='Build 0051'
```

To do so while ignoring case in the grep search:

```
git log --all -i --grep='Build 0051'
```

To search the actual content of commits through a repo's history, use:

```
git grep 'Build 0051' $(git rev-list --all)
```

to show all instances of the given text, the containing file name, and the commit sha1.

And to do this while ignoring case, use:

```
git grep -i 'Build 0051' $(git rev-list --all)
```

Note that this searches the *entire content* of the commit at each stage, and not just the diff changes.  To search just the diff changes, use one of the following:

```
git log -S[searchTerm]
git log -G[searchTerm]
```

Finally, as a last resort in case your commit is dangling and not connected to history at all, you can search the reflog itself with the `-g` flag (short for `--walk-reflogs`:

```
git log -g --grep='Build 0051'
```

EDIT: if you seem to have lost your history, check the `reflog` as your safety net. Look for Build 0051 in one of the commits listed by

```
git reflog
```

You may have simply set your `HEAD` to a part of history in which the 'Build 0051' commit is not visible, or you may have actually blown it away. The [git-ready reflog](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html)  article may be of help.

**To recover your commit from the reflog**: do a git checkout of the commit you found (and optionally make a new branch or tag of it for reference)

```
git checkout 77b1f718d19e5cf46e2fab8405a9a0859c9c2889
# alternative, using reflog (see git-ready link provided)
# git checkout HEAD@{10}
git checkout -b build_0051 # make a new branch with the build_0051 as the tip
```

Comment: with git grep 'Build 0051' $(git rev-list --all) I get sh.exe": /bin/git: Bad file number has the way to do this changed maybe?

Comment: git log -i -grep

Comment: @JensSchauder If you run into an error with `git grep 'search' $(git rev-list --all)`, try `git rev-list --all | xargs git grep 'search'`

Comment: On Windows I had to use double-quotes instead of single-quotes to get this to work.

Comment: @shelhamer What's the difference between `git log --all --grep='Build 0051'`  and `git grep 'Build 0051' $(git rev-list --all)`?

Comment: Use `--fixed-strings` to interpret commit message as literal strings and not regex, which is usually the intended usage.

Answer (score 112):

I put this in my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    find = log --pretty=\"format:%Cgreen%H %Cblue%s\" --name-status --grep
```

Then I can type "git find string" and I get a list of all the commits containing that string in the message. For example, to find all commits referencing ticket #33:

```
029a641667d6d92e16deccae7ebdeef792d8336b Added isAttachmentEditable() and isAttachmentViewable() methods. (references #33)
M       library/Dbs/Db/Row/Login.php

a1bccdcd29ed29573d2fb799e2a564b5419af2e2 Add permissions checks for attachments of custom strategies. (references #33).
M       application/controllers/AttachmentController.php

38c8db557e5ec0963a7292aef0220ad1088f518d Fix permissions. (references #33)
M       application/views/scripts/attachment/_row.phtml

041db110859e7259caeffd3fed7a3d7b18a3d564 Fix permissions. (references #33)
M       application/views/scripts/attachment/index.phtml

388df3b4faae50f8a8d8beb85750dd0aa67736ed Added getStrategy() method. (references #33)
M       library/Dbs/Db/Row/Attachment.php
```

Comment: Nice, but perhaps missing a colour reset? `--pretty=\"format:%Cgreen%H %Cblue%s%Creset\"`

Comment: I prefer to print the full git message (grep may be happened there, not in the title), so I ended up with: `find = log --all --pretty=\"format:%Cgreen%H %Cblue%s\n%b%Creset\" --name-status --grep`. Note the `--all` and `%b` chars. Thx @AshleyCoolman for the `reset` tip.

Comment: Thanks. I found the alias very useful. I didn't like the coloring and found the oneline format perfect for this. Also adding -i to make it case-insensitive was helpful. e.g. `find = log --oneline --name-status -i --grep`

Answer (score 73):

Though a bit late, there is `:/` which is the dedicated notation to specify a commit (or revision) based on the commit message, just prefix the search string with `:/`, e.g.:

```
git show :/keyword(s)
```

Here `<keywords>` can be a single word, or a complex regex pattern consisting of whitespaces, so please make sure to quote/escape when necessary, e.g.:

```
git log -1 -p ":/a few words"
```

Alternatively, a start point can be specified, to find the closest commit reachable from a specific point, e.g.:

```
git show 'HEAD^{/fix nasty bug}'
```

See: [git revisions manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

Comment: Cool, didn't know that! Now how can I get the parent commit using this notation? The usual `^` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Easy :-) you just do it with two git commands, like `git rev-parse $(git rev-parse :/keyword)~` @AndreiToroplean

Comment: @ryenus actually `@^{/fix nasty bug}` (never write HEAD, `@` is enough) is a commit in it its own right, so `@^{/fix nasty bug}^` just works

Comment: @usretc yes that's right, `@` alone is just a shorthand for `HEAD`, see https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#Documentation/revisions.txt-emem

Answer (score 36):

```
git log --grep="Build 0051"
```

should do the trick

Comment: Have to use double quotes (") instead of single quotes (').

Answer (score 31):

```
git log --grep=<pattern>
            Limit the commits output to ones with log message that matches the
            specified pattern (regular expression).
```

Answer (score 19):

Try this!

```
git log | grep -b3 "Build 0051"
```

Comment: Thanks - but its not finding it. How do I search across all possible branches?

Comment: You want to use `git grep` instead of normal grep, and provide the `--all` flag to search multiple branches.

Comment: Hmm - are the other answers finding it either? If not, you might have a bigger problem. I'd try `git log --all --grep='Build 0051'` (@shelhamer's answer)

Comment: I tried "git log --all", and it only lists versions to 0046. Version 0051 was on a different branch. I rolled back to 0043, and 0051 disappeared.

Comment: Sounds like you may have lost your history when you rolled back?

Comment: Version 0051 was branched off 0043. Is it possible for GIT to just randomly delete source code?

Comment: @Gravitas, try my example that uses the reflog: the one with `git log -g`. You may have lost history in a reset, but you can still check the reflog if it hasn't been garbage collected.

Answer (score 10):

Just a small addition to the `git log --all --grep` command:
In my case I had to escape the brackets inside the message:

```
git log --all --grep="\[C\] Ticket-1001: Fix nasty things"
```

Comment: After finding the commit, you may want to find it's branch: `git branch -a --contains <hash>` (Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707110/557406)

Answer (score 9):

first to list the commits use

```
git log --oneline
```

then find the SHA of the commit (Message), then I used

```
 git log --stat 8zad24d
```

(8zad24d) is the SHA assosiated with the commit you are intrested in (the first couples sha example (8zad24d) you can select 4 char  or 6 or 8 or the entire sha) to find the right info

Answer (score 9):

To search across all the branches

```
git log --all --grep='Build 0051'
```

Once you know which commit you want to get to

```
git checkout <the commit hash>
```

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who wants to pass in arbitrary strings which are exact matches (And not worry about escaping regex special characters), [git log takes a --fixed-strings option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/2.19.0)

```
git log --fixed-strings --grep "$SEARCH_TERM"
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Shows all previous commits.

Answer (score 3):

If the change is not too old, you can do,

`git reflog`

and then checkout the commit id

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
git log --oneline --grep='Searched phrase'
```

or this:

```
git log --oneline --name-status --grep='Searched phrase'
```

commands work best for me.

Answer (score -2):

in `gitk` you can search by commit message:

[image]

You can install gitk by command `sudo apt install gitk`