# Search Git Commits Using Regex

Tags: regex, git, command-line

I have a Git repository that contains hundreds of commits and several branches. How to search a particular commit that contains a certain string e.g. "helper function"? Ideally, the string can be denoted by a regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-in-the-git-history

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Credits go to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124949/583539):

```
git log --all --grep='Build 0051'

# case insensitive
git log --all --grep='Build 0051' -i
```

Comment: This looks for the regex in the commit message as opposed to knittl's answer, where -G<regex> searches through the commit's diff.

Answer (score 42):

Newer versions of Git support `git log -G<regex>`:

```
git log -G'helper.*function' --full-history --all
```

This command will search for the regex in the diff of each commit, and only display commits which introduced a change that matches the regex.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, and how I understood the question was written.