# Look up commit log for commit ID in Git

Tags: git

I want to look at a commit by ID. For instance, I want to know the code that got committed for that ID, something like:

```
git log <commit_id>
```

And this would display the committed code and commit message that corresponds to this ID.

Comment: The `-p` can be useful here too.

Answer (score 198):

```
git show <commit_id>
```

is the droid you are looking for, probably.

Comment: How can I find the name of the branch in which is the commit I'm looking for? I can see just commit ID, Author, Date and diff of the commit. But I can't find the name of the branch where the commit can be found.

Comment: @Vojta: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/finding-what-branch-a-git-commit-came-from otherwise known as: `git branch --contains <commit>`

Comment: Actually you need to put two dashes after the commit id: `git show XXXX --` It is required to differentiate between a file and a commit ID.

Comment: This also shows the patch. So you have to to do `git show <commit_id> --no-patch` if you want to see the same look as `git log`

Answer (score 32):

@SethRobertson's solution works for me but it shows a diff. I wanted to see it exactly like `git log` shows it. So add `--no-patch`:

```
git show <commit_id> --no-patch
```

I learned this from - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31448684/1828637

Answer (score 4):

## Search for commits in repository history

### Search commit by message

**MODEL**

```
git log --all --grep='<MENSAGE_CONTENT>'
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
git log --all --grep='Merge pull request #240'
```

### Search commit by hash

**MODEL**

```
git show <COMMIT_HASH> --no-patch
git show <COMMIT_HASH_PART> --no-patch
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
git show b8c3fd58a0db675a6d9b9e819419f6ebc967278a --no-patch
git show b8c3fd5 --no-patch
```

[Ref(s).: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124949/3223785 ,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53685160/3223785 ]