# How can I extract the email of a commiter using git?

Tags: linux, git, grep, git-log

If I have a specific string how can I use e.g `git log` to find the email of the committer from the command line?
I don't want to see the commit. I only want the "one-liner" command to give me **only** the email of the author.

**NOTE:** I do **NOT** have a commit id. I only have a search string. I mean a string that I know is part of a commit for sure.

**Update after comment from @axiac:**
I have a string X that is "unique" in the sense that is introduced by only 1 committer. The committer adds it to file `foo.java`.
I want having only the string `X` and `foo.java` to find the email of the commiter who added the string

Comment: *"I only have a string"* - you have to be more specific. What string do you have? I guess it's not the committer's email, you said it's not a commit hash. What is it then? A fragment from the commit message? A fragment from a file? Do you know the name of the file?

Comment: @axiac:It is just a string that I know for sure it is part of *a* commit.

Comment: It's still not clear. All the strings mentioned above (committer's name and email, commit message, commit date, file names and contents) are part of the commit. Which one is the one you know?

Comment: @axiac: I only have a string that is "unique" in a sense that 99% of the time it will be introduced/affected by only 1 commiter. I did not have a specific file in mind but now that you mention it, it is for certain part of a certain file e.g. `foo.java`. I only need the email of the commiter

Comment: Try `git log` with the `-G` option

Comment: @AndrewC: Just `-G`?

Comment: No, more like `git log -G <string X> --pretty=%ce` You may need to pass in additional ref-specs if the commit you are after isn't reachable from HEAD.

Comment: @AndrewC:I am sorry for my question, but I don't know what "additional ref-specs" is supposed to be

Comment: Just pass in `--all` to be safe

Comment: Relevant question. Why so many downvotes? @Avalanche's answer is helpful.

Answer (score 9):

```
git --no-pager log -s --format="%ae"
```

[Source](http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-simplest-git-command-to-get-a-commits-author-and-their-email-address-if-available).

Comment: But I don't have a commit id. I only have a string

Comment: Very confusing description, try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/7124949/1125161

Comment: You can also extract a unique list of emails by doing: `git --no-pager log -s --format="%ae" | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 1):

How about `git log --grep="YOUR_SEARCH_REGEX" --pretty=format"%ce"`

Comment: You should add `--all` to extend the search to the entire repo.