# Finding a revision by commit message

Tags: git, revision-history, commit-message

I know this kind of thing gets asked a lot (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124914/how-to-search-a-git-repository-by-commit-message)), but (maybe because of this) I have not been able to find what I'm looking for.

I know that I can specify a commit by a pattern matching its commit message, instead of by its hash, like this:

```
git show ":/rename function X to function Y"
```

This shows me the most recent commit whose message starts with the given pattern, without me having to search for its hash first.

My questions are:

1. What is the name of this feature, and where is it documented? (searching Google for `:/` is futile)
2. How can I get the *parent* of that commit? This does not work:

   ```
   git show ":/pattern"^
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit ugly, and there may be a better way, but you could use something like the following to find the parent:

```
git show $(git rev-parse ":/pattern")^
```

`git rev-parse` gives the SHA1 for the specified revision, to which you can apply operators such as `^`.  Alternatively, you could use `git name-rev --name-only`, which will give a symbolic name for the revision (e.g. `master~10`).

Answer (score 1):

The `:/` syntax does not appear to have a dedicated name and is documented in the [gitrevisions(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) manual page.