# How to find files changed by commits message

Tags: git

I need to get file list from all branch where commit message contain bug id (eg. 1000 and 2000)
can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: what did you tried?

Comment: You can find commits which have your bug Id ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124914/how-to-search-a-git-repository-by-commit-message)) and than find files

Comment: Add `--stat` to the linked question's accepted answer, and it will show the files touched by each matching commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to the git initialized folder and execute the command.

```
 git show :/bug_id
```

bug_id in your case.

Answer (score 5):

This command will show you all committed files into every commit with the message, containing *Build-ID* substring:

```
git log --graph --pretty=oneline --name-only --grep="bug_id"
```

Comment: allmost, this retrive files sepearate with commit id, how do i pu more the 1 bugId ?

Comment: @user2290492 as I remember, you can use `|` syntax for grep equation, such as `git log --graph --pretty=oneline --name-only --grep="bug_id_1\|bug_id_2"
`

Comment: grate! 
You help me a lot.
Thanks