# Can you search github network commit messages?

Tags: github

Upon brief Google and SO search, I couldn't find any info on this. I am looking at this Github repo which hasn't been updated for years, but there are many forks that are still being developed actively. Is there any way to search through commit messages from different forks of this Github repo network?

Comment: your best bet is search via Google with something like `site:github.com project-name keyword-in-commit-message` it will also depends on the forks doesn't change the project name

Comment: thanks, that works to an extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the Google search already mentioned, another more precise alternative, if that repo is not *too* big, is to:

- list all the forks with [this API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/) `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/forks`
- clone them, and do a [`git grep`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124949/6309) in each of those local clones.

That way, you are *sure* to have a complete search.
See also the [python `frost-nzcr4/find_forks` script](https://github.com/frost-nzcr4/find_forks).

Answer (score 0):

View the Developer Tools while you're loading the repo network page. In the log you'll notice there's two urls - "meta" and "chunk".

Meta is the (json) list of all the users who are in the network and various properties needed to draw the graph, and "chunk" is the commit log from all the users in the graph, which is used to render the tooltips that come up.

Save these outputs and use your favourite text editor / command line tool to search the commit messages.