# How to search Git commit messages with regular expression and output those messages & their line number to a text file

Tags: git, msr

How to search Git commit messages (not diffs) in a software repository with regular expression and output those messages & their line number to a text file?

Comment: Potential duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124914)?

Comment: It is similar, but I also need outputting line number and regular expression search option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can 'grep' through commit log messages by doing the following:

```
git log -E --grep="regex" --oneline >/tmp/results.txt
```

This will result in e.g.:

> abcd1234 First commit containing regex word.
> defg5679 Another commit: regex is found here.

I'm not sure what you mean by line number - if you just want every line in the file numbered, you can achieve this by piping the results through `nl`:

```
git log -E --grep "foo" | nl -w 1 -s ' ' > /tmp/results.txt
```

(`-w 1` left-aligns numbers, and `-s ' '` puts a single space after the number before the text).