# How can I filter `git whatchanged` by commit message?

Tags: git

Say I have a repository with some commits that have commit messages that start with "Update foo to". I would like to see all file changes in only those commits.

So could the output of `git whatchanged` to be filtered to only show commits with commit messages that start with "Update foo to"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `git log` is preferred, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124949/3741208) will help?
To show the full diff using the suggested command from the answer, you could use `git log --all -p --grep="Update foo to"`

Comment: I didn't know about the `--grep` switch. That's perfect and a lot simpler than I was expecting any solution to be.