# How to find latest squash commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-log

How can I find the latest squashed commit?

Clarification: I mean a commit created by the command

```bash
git merge --squash branch
```

Ideally I'd like to know how I can find the second-to-last merge or squash commit, but if I get an answer to my primary question, I can probably figure out the rest.

Comment: @mkrieger1 a commit created by `git merge --squash`

Comment: Does `branch` still exist unchanged after the merge? If yes, do you know the set of possible branches that `branch` can be?

Answer (score 3):

Technically there is no way to tell if a commit is squashed or not.  When you rebase and squash commits, you are just making a new commit with those changes and there is no difference (as far as git is concerned) to just having done the changes and made a new commit.

Now if in your workflow you adjust the commit message to identify that the commit was squashed, you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124949/498699) to search through the log and find the commit that was squashed.