# Searching checkin messages in git

Tags: git

Does git allow you to search for a query string in all checkin messages.

e.g. I want to get all the checkins which contain "quest" in their checkin message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```
git log -g --grep=search_for_this
```

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746684/how-to-search-through-all-commits-in-the-repository).