# Git-Repo searching for String in all committed files (unknown branch and commit)

Tags: git

I have a piece of code in another than my current branch in my git repo, and I am not sure which commit and which branch. How can I search in all files that I committed until now for a specific string (and afterwards show the surrounding of that line of code)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746684/how-to-search-through-all-commits-in-the-repository

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use `git grep` to locate the commit:

```
git grep "string" $(git rev-list --all)
```

The `git rev-list --all` makes it search the entire history of the project.

That will give an output like this:

```
<commit>:<path>:<matched line>
```

Then you can use `git branch --contains` to find out which branch the commit is on:

```
git branch --contains <commit>
```

Comment: Can I specify to search in only one file/path? (E.g. I am searching for a specific fixture and only want to search in this path)

Comment: Yes: `git grep "string" $(git rev-list --all) -- path`.

Comment: this doesn't work for big histories :( 
`git grep 'abc' echo $(git rev-list --all)`
`zsh: argument list too long: git`

Comment: If you get `Argument list too long`, you can use `git rev-list --all | xargs git grep 'abc'`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49243541/9636

Answer (score 11):

If the `git grep "string"` variation above is giving you "list too long" errors, you can use `git log -S` instead. The -S option searches the contents of the files that were committed:

```
git log -S "string"  # look for string in every file of every commit
git log -S "string" -- path/to/file  # only look at the history of the named file
```

(More in the "Pro Git" book under ["searching"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Searching#Git-Log-Searching).)

Answer (score 6):

If [jszakmeister's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13878026/9636) gives you an `Argument list too long` response:

```
$ git grep "string" $(git rev-list --all)
-bash: /usr/local/bin/git: Argument list too long
```

You can pipe it into `xargs` instead:

```
$ git rev-list --all | xargs git grep "string"
```

Comment: How to escape this command after it is done?

Comment: What do you mean by `escape this command`?

Comment: Anyway to avoid `xargs: git: terminated by signal 11` ?

Answer (score 0):

change the branch with `git branch "branch-name"` and then do `git grep "specific string"` in your repository root. if you don't have too many branches this should get you there quick enough.