# git --all missing commit

Tags: git

Can someone please help me understand what's happening here?

I start with `git log --oneline`, which spits out:

```
4df9421 (HEAD, master) moved some aliases around
d3810e4 (origin/master) some terminal color changes
a7182d3 git colors, ignores, etc.
995fe8c added gitconfig, moved some personal stuff out of the public repo
8a100b7 misc unimportant updates
55d2c08 added a fix to "open with", refactored
7ec7d83 Removed some vim colors; added a couple searching aliases
330c7fc Minor updates
44e80a1 Added vim files
48537c6 Fixed some formatting problems
14933a2 Initial Commit
```

then I do `git reset --hard 330c7fc` which takes the log back to:

```
330c7fc (HEAD, master) Minor updates
44e80a1 Added vim files
48537c6 Fixed some formatting problems
14933a2 Initial Commit
```

So far so good, but (now that I've reset) when I do `git log --oneline --all` I get:

```
 d3810e4 (origin/master) some terminal color changes
 a7182d3 git colors, ignores, etc.
 995fe8c added gitconfig, moved some personal stuff out of the public repo
 8a100b7 misc unimportant updates
 55d2c08 added a fix to "open with", refactored
 7ec7d83 Removed some vim colors; added a couple searching aliases
 330c7fc (HEAD, master) Minor updates
 44e80a1 Added vim files
 48537c6 Fixed some formatting problems
 14933a2 Initial Commit
```

Notice that the most recent entry, "4df9421 moved some aliases around", is missing from this list.

My understanding is that the `--all` option should display all the commits. Why is the latest missing once I revert to an earlier commit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is missing, because it isn't reference anymore by HEAD or by a branch.
You have reset both (HEAD and master) to another commit, with your `git reset --hard`.

Only [`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) would show you that recent commit.

[`git log --all`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) is only for listing commits referenced in `refs/` (like tags, heads, ...)

```
--all
```

> Pretend as if all the refs in `refs/` are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.

Comment: Got it. That makes sense. I guess it's advisable then to always keep one of your branches on the most recent commit, and if you want to revert to something earlier, do it in a branch.

Comment: @OliverTaylor yes: that way, you keep a reference on the old HEAD, which will then be still visible in the `git log --all`.

Comment: Which brings up the question, is there a way to combine the commits in reflog with the commits in log? Thus creating a sort-of master list of all commits, regardless of their presence in refs/

Comment: @OliverTaylor this is generally not advisable, in order to avoid all the pollution left by similar commits dereferenced after, for instance, a rebase (where you get 2 sets of identical commits). That being said, have a look to the `--walk-reflogs` option of `git log`. (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/746790/6309)

Answer (score 2):

The `--all` option does **not** tell `git log` to display all *commits*.  It asks for the logs of all *refs*, basically your branches and tags. The reset command removed that commit from `master`, the only ref that had included it so that commit is now unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

You should accept [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15426496/86072). To complete it :

The "missing commit" was not pushed to the server, or saved in another branch. Your `git reset --hard` thus *deleted* it.

Fortunately, git has some sort of magic undo stack : `git reflog`. Check VonC's link to figure out how to get it back.

Be careful when you use `git reset`, this command can destroy commits.

As a rule of thumb : before you manipulate your history, make sure you still have some way of getting back to where you were. My local repositories are crippled with `backup`, `orig` and `wip` branches, which I clean up every month or so.

Comment: "deleted it"? Not exactly. It "*dereferenced it*". Unless you do a `git gc --prune=today --aggressive` (or `git gc --prune=now`), it is still listed in the reflog (for the next 90 days, by default).

Comment: You are of course right. If anything, you wouldn't be able to recover it otherwise. In a "normal git flow" however, it looks like you really have deleted your commit.