# git - how to apply to a transform to all past commit messages?

Tags: git, launchpad

I'm trying to import a project to launchpad, but this fails with the error:

```
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-17114/bzrplugins/git/fetch.py", line 119, in import_git_blob
    ie = cls(file_id, name.decode("utf-8"), parent_id)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

So I'm wondering how can I search all commit logs for this "0xca" char and remove it? Looking manually at the history with QGit doesn't show any out of place chars.

Comment: This may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746684/how-to-search-through-all-commits-in-the-repository-for-a-certain-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able use `git log --grep...` to find bad commits and fix them manually (not sure if unicode will work with `--grep`). If there are too many to fix manually, or you want to automate the process, consider using `git filter-branch --msg-filter <command>` to modify every commit message by executing the shell command `<command>`. Here is a simple example of using `--msg-filter`:

```
   mkdir tmp
   cd tmp
   git init
   touch a
   git add .
   git ci -am 'first commit'
   touch b
   git add .
   git ci -am 'second commit'
   git log --oneline
   git filter-branch --msg-filter 'sed "s/^/hello /"'
   git log --oneline
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562354/remove-unicode-characters-from-textfiles-sed-other-bash-shell-methods) for possibly how to fill in `<command>` with a command that will suitably alter the unicode in your commit messages.

You can then inspect the changes by running

```
diff <(git log original/refs/heads/<your-branch> --oneline | cut -d' ' -f 2-) <(git log <your-branch> --oneline | cut -d' ' -f 2-)
```

Comment: Excellent - I'll give this a try later and accept if it works

Comment: [`git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) has a [similar capability](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_generic_callback_code_snippets), but you need to write a bit of [python](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#CALLBACKS)